# Trouble setting up computer with ROS Kinetic, Gazebo 9, and latest gazebo_ros_pkgs

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setting up a computer to use ROS kinetic, Gazebo 9, and the latest version of `gazebo_ros_pkgs` (from source) is giving errors.  They are basically `controller type 'fu/bar' not exist`.

```
[ INFO] [1524592104.175529525, 0.137000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1524592104.175757532, 0.137000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /
[ INFO] [1524592104.176666268, 0.137000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ INFO] [1524592104.309520405, 0.137000000]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
[ INFO] [1524592104.331149974, 0.159000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
Loaded joint_state_controller
[ERROR] [1524592104.335562797, 0.163000000]: Could not load controller 'arm_controller' because controller type 'position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1524592104.335600886, 0.163000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
Error when loading arm_controller
[ERROR] [1524592104.339144617, 0.167000000]: Could not load controller 'gripper_fake_controller' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1524592104.339186543, 0.167000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
Error when loading gripper_fake_controller
[ERROR] [1524592104.343053113, 0.171000000]: Could not load controller 'mobile_base_fake_controller' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1524592104.343081991, 0.171000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
Error when loading mobile_base_fake_controller
Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
[ERROR] [1524592104.349697714, 0.177000000]: Could not start controller with name arm_controller because no controller with this name exists
Error when starting  ['arm_controller']
[ERROR] [1524592104.352091520, 0.180000000]: Could not start controller with name gripper_fake_controller because no controller with this name exists
Error when starting  ['gripper_fake_controller']
[ERROR] [1524592104.354369094, 0.183000000]: Could not start controller with name mobile_base_fake_controller because no controller with this name exists
Error when starting  ['mobile_base_fake_controller']
```

Based on [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/284241/mobile-arm-simulation-behaves-strangely-when-adding-ros_control-plugin-for-arm/?answer=284396#post-id-284396), I set up the new computer as follows

- sudo apt remove --purge ros-kinetic-*
- sudo apt remove gazebo7 gazebo7-common gazebo7-plugin-base
- [Install ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)
- sudo apt remove --purge ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs
- Remove gazebo again?
- [Install Gazebo 9](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install)
- [Install gazebo_ros_pkgs from source](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros)

Thanks for looking at this.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

**Edit:**
Running `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-position-controllers` and `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-effort-controllers` helped with most of the errors but I am still left with

```
[ERROR] [1524614845.792391368, 0.313000000]: Could not load controller 'arm_controller' because controller type 'position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1524614845.792423207, 0.313000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types
```

The output of `rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types` is

```
types: [effort_controllers/JointEffortController, effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController, effort_controllers/JointGroupPositionController, effort_controllers/JointPositionController, effort_controllers/JointVelocityController, joint_state_controller/JointStateController, position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController, position_controllers/JointPositionController]
base_classes: ['controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase']
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289582/trouble-setting-up-computer-with-ros-kinetic,-gazebo-9,-and-latest-gazebo_ros_pkgs/) by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 368 on 2018-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following package-installation commands took care of this problem.

```
sudo apt install ros-kinetic-position-controllers ros-kinetic-effort-controllers ros-kinetic-joint-trajectory-controller ros-kinetic-robot-state-publisher
```

---

Originally posted by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) with karma: 368 on 2018-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As raequin indicates, your problem is about not having installed the required ros-kinetic controller packages. That problem is not related to Gazebo 9. The same error would appear in any other Gazebo version if those packages are not installed.

Related to the way of installing Gazebo 9 on Kinetic, here I wrote a [step by step guide](http://www.theconstructsim.com/all-about-gazebo-9-with-ros/) that can be useful.

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2018-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2018-05-21**:
Thanks for the guide!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Starting from the edited question, I found a solution when installing Gazebo 9 with ROS Kinetic Kame. Here the [link to the complete guide](https://github.com/gsilano/BebopS). I made it for my ROS package, but it is not so much difficult to adapt it for your own purposes.

Remove Gazebo 7 and all related packages, and then install Gazebo 9:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ros-kinetic-gazebo* gazebo*
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
$ wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gazebo9 gazebo9-* ros-kinetic-gazebo9-*
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Additional packages are required to build ROS packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev ros-kinetic-image-view ros-kinetic-parrot-arsdk libprotobuf-dev libprotoc-dev ros-kinetic-joy-teleop ros-kinetic-nav-msgs ros-kinetic-mav-msgs libyaml-cpp-dev ros-kinetic-nodelet ros-kinetic-mav-planning-msgs ros-kinetic-urdf ros-kinetic-image-transport ros-kinetic-roslint ros-kinetic-angles ros-kinetic-cv-bridge ros-kinetic-tf2-geometry-msgs ros-kinetic-xacro ffmpeg libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev ros-kinetic-camera-info-manager ros-kinetic-cmake-modules ros-kinetic-gazebo-msgs ros-kinetic-mavros-msgs ros-kinetic-control-toolbox ros-kinetic-mav-msgs ros-kinetic-libmavconn ros-kinetic-mavros ros-kinetic-octomap-msgs ros-kinetic-geographic-msgs ros-kinetic-mavlink ros-kinetic-mavros-extras ros-kinetic-mav-planning-msgs ros-kinetic-joy
```

Make Gazebo 9 compatible with ROS Kinetic Kame

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir -p ros-kinetic-gazebo9-pkgs
$ cd ros-kinetic-gazebo9-pkgs
$ git clone -b feature/ros-kinetic-gazebo9-pkgs https://github.com/gsilano/BebopS.git
$ chmod 777 gazebo9.sh
$ ./gazebo9.sh
```

---

Originally posted by [Giuseppe Silano](https://answers.ros.org/users/44159/giuseppe-silano/) with karma: 21 on 2019-12-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-27**:
+100 for posting here, but <del>if</del> when `gsilano/BebopS` gets deleted or changed, the guide you refer to may disappear. That would leave future readers with nothing.

It would be great if you could include the pertinent parts of your guide here in your answer, as that would make the answer stand-alone and infinitely increase the value of your answer.

**Comment by [Giuseppe Silano](https://answers.ros.org/users/44159/giuseppe-silano/) on 2019-12-27**:
I totally agree with you, but I created a script and collected binary files to handle the problem. If you know a repository that will remain always available, I will immediately push my code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-27**:
I would still recommend you post at least a summary here, because even without the files it will probably help future readers.

**Comment by [Giuseppe Silano](https://answers.ros.org/users/44159/giuseppe-silano/) on 2019-12-27**:
I edited my previous reply reporting part of my guide (the complete guide is reported on GitHub)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-27**:
Thank you very much.

Please note that your script appears to be copying files to system-managed locations and this tends to be very brittle. If/when anything gets updated `apt` may refuse to do so and leave you with broken packages and other problems.

I'm also confused: isn't Gazebo 9 available for Ubuntu Xenial by adding the `packages.osrfoundation.org` repository and installing the binaries?

**Comment by [Giuseppe Silano](https://answers.ros.org/users/44159/giuseppe-silano/) on 2019-12-27**:
Gazebo 9 is available for Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) but when you follow the [official guide](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install) it does not work with the [RotorS package](https://github.com/ethz-asl/rotors_simulator). The problem appears to be related to some Gazebo packages for ROS which should be compiled from source. Maybe my solution is not the cleanest, but it works. That's why I decided to share it.